# Does Typescript support extracted interface by excluding another interface's properties?

Tags: typescript

I wonder if it has any of the following features. I tried Google but I couldn't find it out. Thanks!

```
interface Numbers {
    number: number;
    number2: number;
    number3: number;
}

const numbers:Numbers - { number3 } = {
    number: 1,
    number2: 2
};
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/)? It explains (with examples) what one can and cannot do with [interfaces](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html).

Comment: @axiac Thanks! I've already read it before, but not entirely. and I've read the interface section once more according to your advice. :)

Comment: Based on the answer you get, it seems reading the release notes of each version is required to be up to date with the language: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html. I started reading them too.

Comment: @axiac I appreciate your kindness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**

As of Typescript 3.5 `Omit` is part of the predefined types Typescript comes with.

**Original answer**

You can do this in 2.8 using the new `Exclude` conditional type and the `Pick` mapped type

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>; 

interface Numbers {
    number: number;
    number2: number;
    number3: number;
}

const numbers:Omit<Numbers, 'number3'> = {
    number: 1,
    number2: 2
};
```

Before 2.8 `Omit` could be defined like this:

```
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[P in T]: P } & {[P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];  
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Diff<keyof T, K>>;
```

Comment: I was trying to figure out by Exclude was introduced in 2.8, but it did not work to me. Good solution. Thank you for teaching me. :)